# angular 2: subscribing to observable yield "undefined"?

Tags: angular, observable

i have a simple service which gets the repos of github users and correctly returns an *array object*.

**githubservice**

```
 getRepos(){
      return  this._http.get(this._url + this.username +"/repos")
      .map(users =>{         
             this.u = users.json();
             console.log("getRepos", this.u); //<== correctly returns array object
          });
    }
```

when i subscribe to it in component, then i get undefined.

**githubcomponent**

```
 getReposFromGithub(){
       return  this._githubService.getRepos().subscribe(repos => {
         this.repos = repos; 
         console.log("repos", repos);},  //<== logs 'undefined' 
         (error)=> console.log("error message",error), //<== no error message
         ()=>{console.log("completed");} //<== gets logged 
         );
     }


 ngOnInit() {
         console.log("on changes");
         this.getReposFromGithub();  
     }
```

fyi, here is the array object returned

[image]

what am i missing here ?maybe some rxjs operator to be used  ?
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the `.map` call in `getRepos()`. You probably mean to return the resulting array. Add `return this.u;`, like so:

```
 getRepos() {
   return this._http.get(this._url + this.username +"/repos")
     .map(users => {         
       this.u = users.json();
       console.log("getRepos", this.u); //<== correctly returns array object
       return this.u;
   });
 }
```

Comment: thanks. i knew it would be a silly mistake from my end. i can also use `.map(users =>  users.json());` in single line.

Comment: @candidJ It happens. :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda function you use with `map` in `getRepos` doesn't return anything.

Comment: thanks. I initially used single line (so no need to use return) but then thought of logging result to console.